A thriller about a stalking dolphin
This question should be easy to answer, but strangely, it is not. In about 1990, I watched a movie, whose title is translated into Vietnamese as "The dolphin's revenge" or "Dolphin avenges". It is American, which looks like something made in the 80's. 
The cinema's sound system sucked, which makes me quite unable to follow the plot, but the gist is as follows: A ship traveling in some icy water - probably near the North Pole - shot a dolphin. I am not sure whether that dolphin survived and stalked them for revenge, or its mate did. So the dolphin ambushed the people in similar fashion to Jaws. After 2 hours matching wits with the dolphin, one man survived and ended up on some ice floating over the water, then the dolphin hit the ice with its nose, breaking the ice and drowning him.
I tried searching with all the keywords that may apply, getting no result. No title with "dolphin" from imdb matches. It is not "The day of the dolphin", as anyone who has watched the latter could tell immediately. 

I can't be sure as I've never seen any film like that but after a quick google I found the film Orca which seems to match your description.

That must be it - which explains my failure to find the movie all those years! Imagine it: a whale translated as "dolphin"! Thank you and your sharp mind.

What search term did you use, so that I could gain some useful experience in googling?

Well you weren't wrong since killer whales are the largest of the dolphin family but I simply took the information you provided and put it into google I think I typed 'What is the film where a dolphin is killing everybody on a boat' and it was the first thing to pop up. Google did suggest I searched for the same phrase replacing 'killing' with 'attacking' but that brought up a load of other results so I couldn't say where you may have gone wrong as it was your information that led me to the answer but glad I could help you out.
